# Screen and Mobile Stylesheets

Tags: css, mobile, screen, stylesheet

I've looked through the stack overflow topics on this question, as well as some google search results but I can't seem to solve my issue.

I've created a stylesheet for mobile devices(mobile.css) which is essentially a copy of my main.css with changes to many of the attributes.  When I load only mobile.css as the stylesheet it looks great on my iPhone, just how I want it to.  However when I put both in, I am getting a mix of both, but more of the main.css

Any idea why?

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-device-width: 480px)' href='styles/mobile.css' type='text/css' />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
```

Comment: My code isn't showing up for some reason when I posted it... Could you look at the source at: www.cuhvz.com/sandbox/home.php

Comment: Fixed it. It should work now.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

According to [documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries), syntax of loading another file in specific device/condition is like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 400px)" href="mobile.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 401px)" href="desktop.css" />
```

This will load only one css file for every single amount of `width`

For iPhone 4 and new generation iPod touch that have Retina display there is something that you should note. iPhone 4 width is `640` pixels that many developers don't count this width as a mobile browser width. If you add this below meta tag in your document problem will be solved

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320">
```

This meta tag will impact your images quality. If you want to fix that problem then you need to read about this [here](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/iphone4-ios4-detection-safari-viewport).

Comment: Sorry, none of the markup got posted for some reason, perhaps I forgot to format it as code. (www.cuhvz.com/sandbox/home.php)

Comment: You need to add `media="screen and (min-width: 480px)"` to your `main.css`

Comment: Added `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` - people coming to this answer from Google and copy-pasting blindly - without this line the code doesn't work well.

Comment: I have a question. If i make these stylesheets separated, would it make website even faster or would only make it load even more stylesheet?

Answer (score 3):

Its hard to know without any markup but i'm guessing you should do something like:
http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/blog/about/hardboiled_css3_media_queries

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css" /> // has all the common classes
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile.css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 320px)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="largescreen.css" media="screen and (min-device-width: 321px)" />
```

Comment: Sorry, none of the markup got posted for some reason, perhaps I forgot to format it as code. (www.cuhvz.com/sandbox/home.php)

Answer (score 0):

@scott; may be you have to define your `mobile.css` after `main.css` like  this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" media="screen" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile.css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" />
```

or you can define your `mobile css` in your `main.css` like this:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px){
  body {
    background: #ccc;
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

write this `<!DOCTYPE html>` instead of `<DOCTYPE html>` in your html.

Answer (score 0):

Your mobile stylesheet is loaded conditionally, which means that the computer will load *only* the `main.css`, while the iPhone will load *both* `main.css` and `mobile.css`.

If you want to start from scratch when you load the page on the iPhone, just add this chunk of CSS to the top of your `mobile.css`:

```
/*
YUI 3.4.0 (build 3928)
Copyright 2011 Yahoo! Inc. All rights reserved.
Licensed under the BSD License.
http://yuilibrary.com/license/
*/
html{color:#000;background:#FFF}body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,fieldset,legend,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{margin:0;padding:0}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}fieldset,img{border:0}address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal}li{list-style:none}caption,th{text-align:left}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:normal}q:before,q:after{content:''}abbr,acronym{border:0;font-variant:normal}sup{vertical-align:text-top}sub{vertical-align:text-bottom}input,textarea,select{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit}input,textarea,select{*font-size:100%}legend{color:#000}
```

It effectively resets the CSS.